# HTML form using radio button to pass PHP array on

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple HTML form using radio input, consisting of three inputs, namely ONX, BUDAIR and ECC accordingly. When ONX is clicked and submitted, I need it to pass the array $onx on. I have only included the $onx array for simplicity.

I have managed to get it to work using http_build_query, but I want it to be in a form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>

        <?php $onx=array("onx_service",2,3,4,5); 

          print_r($onx); ?>
        <br />
        <!--<form action="radio.php">
            input type="radio" name="service" value="onx"> ONX<br>
            <input type="radio" name="service" value="bud"> BUDAIR<br>
            <input type="radio" name="service" value="ecc"> ECC<br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form> -->

        <?php echo "<a href='radio.php?" . http_build_query($onx) . "'>Select 
          ONX service</a>"; 
           echo "<br>";
           echo $onx[0] . "<br>";
           echo $onx[1] . "<br>";
           echo $onx[2] . "<br>";
           echo $onx[3] . "<br>";
           echo $onx[4] . "<br>";
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

When either of the three radio inputs are clicked, it should pass on the relevant array.
When I manage to get the code working correctly I will add it into the correct file. The "http_build_query($onx)" potion of the code above is a sample of what I am trying to achieve within the form using radio inputs.

Comment: You may notice that the form part is commented out. I am trying to get the result working within the form as per my post.

Comment: "I have managed to get it to work using http_build_query, but I want it to be in a form." Ignore the "http_build_query" part of the code then. I need to achieve what is working in the "http_build_query" but in a form using radio inputs......

Comment: You can only pass one single, scalar value via each input field. So if you want to transport the full information of that shown array, you would need to serialize it into a string format - via `serialize` or `json_encode` for example. Of course you’d need to reverse that serialization on the receiving end then.

Comment: By why do you want to send this data on a round-trip via the client to begin with? You seem to already _have_ that data available on the server side - so you should rather try and bring it into a structure that allows you to access it again by passing a single identifier. Like, put your data for _all_ options into an array, and use the current radio button values as key to look them up again - `$data = ['onx' => [2,3,4,5], 'bud' => …];`